# Generate Jacoco report for integration tests

Tags: gradle, jacoco, gradle-kotlin-dsl, jacoco-plugin

I've created a new test suite called `integrationTest` using the `jvm-test-suite` plugin.

Now I want to generate a jacoco report just for the integration tests.

I create a new gradle task like this:

```
tasks.create<JacocoReport>("jacocoIntegrationTestReport") {
    group = "verification"
    description = "Generates code coverage report for the integrationTest task."

    executionData.setFrom(fileTree(buildDir).include("/jacoco/integrationTest.exec"))

    reports {
        xml.required.set(true)
        html.required.set(true)
    }
}
```

But the generated HTML/XML report is empty. I have run the integration tests before executing the task and the file `integrationTest.exec` exists.

Thanks

Comment: The [JaCoCo Report Aggregation plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_report_aggregation_plugin.html) should automatically work with the JVM Test Suite plugin. You probably want to amend an existing JaCoCo report task (one will be created by applying the [JaCoCo Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#jacoco_plugin)), rather than creating a new one (which will requires a lot of setup). What's the console output of `./gradlew jacocoIntegrationTestReport --info`? Are there messages that explain why the report empty?

Comment: @aSemy That plugin would work but I don't want to aggregate all the modules. I want a report per module as well.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow you. The JaCoCO Report Aggregation plugin doesn't delete individual reports, they'll still be available. Also, it can aggregate reports from within a single subproject.

Comment: @aSemy for instance if I run the task for a module called `book` it will run all integration tests and not only the ones on the `book` module.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the important part of the new JaCoCo report task configuration is to wire the execution data via the `integrationTest` task instead of the exec-file path. The official docs (see [last example here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#default_values_of_the_jacoco_task_extension)) also imply that the source set must be wired as well.

Here is the full build script (Gradle 7.6) that produces a report with command:

`./gradlew :app:integrationTest :app:jacocoIntegrationTestReport`

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts

plugins {
    application
    jacoco
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

testing {
    suites {
        val integrationTest by creating(JvmTestSuite::class) {
            dependencies {
                implementation(project(":app"))
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.register<JacocoReport>("jacocoIntegrationTestReport") {
    executionData(tasks.named("integrationTest").get())
    sourceSets(sourceSets["integrationTest"])

    reports {
        xml.required.set(true)
        html.required.set(true)
    }
}
```